# Using set flag to set true value with helm upgrade in Jenkinsfile

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

In my scripted pipeline, I have a shell script that performs helm upgrade and I have also set some environment variables like below:

```
sh """helm upgrade --install ${someVar} chart-hub/java-${javaVersion} \
...
--set env.vars[1] .name=some_name_here \
--set env.vars[1] .value="123abcdefhgj3457u" \
--set env.vars[2] .name=some_other_name_here \
--set env.vars[2] .value="true" 
...
```

Things were working well until I added `--set env.vars[2] .name=some_other_name_here \` and
`--set env.vars[2] .value="true"` to my pipeline script . I am getting the error `...ReadString: expects " or n but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|, "value":true}], ...`

I have tried enclosing the value like: `'true'`, `"'true'"` and even storing `true` in a variable and then assigning the variable to --set env.vars[2] .value="${myVar}" but the error persists.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or solutions I could try? Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like the type casting from Groovy to shell to Golang between the interpreters is recasting the string to a boolean. I would heavily suspect the shell interpreter is recasting the type. You could write the values with the `writeYaml` method and provide that file as an argument for the values to `helm upgrade`. Would that be ok for your environment?

Comment: Worth a short. I am at my wits end lol but if there is an alternative to storing the value in a separate file, I will be open to that as well. Thanks so much.

Comment: The file would only exist in the job workspace, so it would just be an alternative interface and pipeline code.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind writing it out as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the error `ReadString: expects " or n but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|, "value":true}], ...`

Enclosing the true value like `'"true"'` worked for me.